# Java Server Basic Calculator

Tags: java

In this program, my server takes a command followed by 1 or 2 operands from the client and returns the result of the operation.

I am having trouble in scanning the line of client input and in performing the actual operation in the switch statement, if anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

// Takes in a mathematical operation and the operands from a client and returns the result
// Valid operations are add, sub, multiply, power, divide, remainder, square 
public class MathServer 
{ 
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException 
    { 
        ServerSocket yourSock = new ServerSocket(50000); //put server online
        while(true)  
        { 
            System.out.println("Waiting to accept connection");
            Socket clientSock = yourSock.accept();  //open server to connections
            System.out.println("Connection accepted");
            process(clientSock);                    //process accepted connection
            System.out.println("Connection closed");
        } 
    }  

    //BufferedReader(Reader r)
    static void process(Socket sock) throws IOException 
    {  
        InputStream in = sock.getInputStream(); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)); 
        OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream(); 
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out, true);       

        String input = br.readLine(); //get user input from client         

        while(input != null && !input.equals("bye")) //check for input, if bye exit connection
        {              
            int answer = operate(input); //perform desired operation on user input
            pw.println(answer);          //print out result
            input = br.readLine();       //get next line of input 
        } 
        sock.close(); 
    }  

    //Talk to the client          
    static int operate(String s) 
    { 
        System.out.println(s); //check if same as client input

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(s); 
        String opType = myScanner.next();   //gets desired operation

        System.out.println(opType); //checks for correct operation 

        switch (opType) { 
            case "add": 
                return (myScanner.nextInt() + myScanner.nextInt());
            case "sub":
                return (myScanner.nextInt() - myScanner.nextInt());
            case "multiply":
                return (myScanner.nextInt() * myScanner.nextInt());
            case "power":
                return (int) Math.pow(myScanner.nextInt(), myScanner.nextInt());
            case "divide":
                return myScanner.nextInt() / myScanner.nextInt();
            case "remainder":
                return myScanner.nextInt() % myScanner.nextInt();
            case "square":
                return (int) Math.pow(myScanner.nextInt(), 2);
            default:
                return (int) Math.pow(myScanner.nextInt(), 3);
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the client is sending a new line terminator as part of there command?  `br.readLine` will wait until to reaches a new line terminator (either a `\n` or `\r`)

Comment: No the client is not sending a new line terminator, would that be something that should be included in the client or does the server usually cover things like that?

Comment: No, either the client needs to send a end of line terminator or the server needs to be able to read each character of the incoming input stream. If you want to use `br.readLine`, the client MUST send a end of line terminator as part of the command (and personally, that is the easier approach).  When writing text to the server, simply add a `\n` as the last character to be sent

Comment: As MadProgrammer hints, the exact data you send to your server is up to you (assuming you are writing the server code as well). You just need to make sure that your server is reading the data as the client expects to send it (and vice versa).

Comment: I finished the client program and appended a '\n' to the input and it returned the correct answer. Thanks for the help, I will be right back after I figure out what the next bug is.

Answer (score 1):

As you're reading with `BufferedReade.readLine()` in your server, make sure you send a newline character from your client (common mistake). Also you may need to flush the `OutputStream` from your client. Because of the way that your `Scanner` reads in variables, you need to send in values on a single line from your client, e.g.

```
add 100 200
```

Comment: I am using putty to test out my server, do you know if it accounts for the newline char? Otherwise I can finish up my client and use that instead

Comment: May need to configure the CR character in Putty, the Windows telnet client should be ok in this regard. Btw I answered a [very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542098/math-server-and-client-java-not-working/14542283) a few days ago.

Comment: I searched before I made the topic but did not find that, I can just refer to that from now on. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was the lack of a newline char that was the initial problem

Answer (score 0):

`switch(opType)` won't work for strings.

check with something like

```
if(opType.equals("add")){ //do Add }
else if(opType.equals("sub")){ //do subtraction }
```

etc.

Comment: In Java 7 [it's allowed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html).

Comment: Ok I was definitely supposed to upgrade to Java 7, I forgot about that. Will the type of statement I have now work though?

Comment: @cjw with Java 6 that program won't even compile, so the fact that it compiles, runs and misbehaves seems to indicate you already upgraded to Java 7 :-)

Comment: Haha yes it is Java 7 (facepalm),I guess my question is that when I do my return in the switch statement, is it just substituting the integer into opType or is it putting the integer into opType and then returning it out of the method?